# Another way to access matrix elements in R

Tags: r, matrix

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), ncol=3)

mat[1:2, 1:2]
```

returns new `matrix(c(1,2,4,5), ncol=2)`.

is there anyway to access the matrix elements like plot's x, y position?

some `function(mat, 1:2, 1:2)` returns `c(1,5)` because `mat[1,1]` and `mat[2,2]` are 1,5.

some `function(mat, c(1,1,2), c(2,1,1)` returns

```
c(4, 1, 2)
```

because `mat[1,2], mat[1,1], mat[2,1]` are 4,1,2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access it this way using `cbind`:

```
mat[cbind(1:2, 1:2)]
# [1] 1 5
mat[cbind(c(1, 1, 2), c(2, 1, 1))]
# [1] 4 1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert from matrix "co-ordinates" to element numbers and subset using those:

```
xy2elem <- function(m,x,y) x + nrow(m)*(y-1)

mat[xy2elem(mat,1:2,1:2)]
[1] 1 5
> mat[xy2elem(mat,c(1,1,2),c(2,1,1))]
[1] 4 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another looking-ugly answer myself.

mapply(function(x,y){'['(mat,x,y)} , c(1,2), c(2,3) )

I compared "mat[cbind" and "mapply(function(x,y){'['(mat,x,y)} ,",

and the first one was about 100 times faster! ;-p

using the function xy2elem is as fast as using cbind! Impressive!

Comment: Glad to help. Generally on StackOverflow, while you can answer your own questions, it's better to phrase it directly as an answer (rather than a thank you, as much as I appreciate it). You might like to shorten it or it might get flagged as "Not an Answer."